# Swift: Array of any does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable, jsondecoder

I'm decoding a json response but I'm getting and array of different objects. Here is my implementation:

```
public struct MyDecodable: Decodable {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String
    public var someData: [Any]
}
```

Here is my error:

[image]

My question to any of you is, how can I make this implementation conform to protocol `Decodable`?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Post your JSON response

Comment: Type `Any` doesn’t conform to `Decodable`. It has no way of knowing how to decode an array of `Any`, i.e., `[Any]`. Is the structure of the contents of `someData` really unknown in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Decodable` protocol requires an initializer with a decoder, like the documentation says :

```swift
/// A type that can decode itself from an external representation.
public protocol Decodable {
    /// Creates a new instance by decoding from the given decoder.
    ///
    /// This initializer throws an error if reading from the decoder fails, or
    /// if the data read is corrupted or otherwise invalid.
    ///
    /// - Parameter decoder: The decoder to read data from.
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
}
```

By default with simple types, or other Decodable implemented types, the initializer can be omitted because Swift can automatically map your JSON object to your Swift object.

In your case, the `Any` type is not Decodable :

```
Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Decodable', only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

So, you should type your array with a specific generic type (it's the better solution), or either, write a specific decoding process in the decoding initializer :

```
public struct MyDecodable: Decodable {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String
    public var someData: [Any]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case someData
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        // Do your stuff here to evaluate someData from your json
    }
}
```

More infos here (Swift4) : https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with you while trying to create a `URLSession` request method. I ended up using generics like this:

```
public struct MyDecodable<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String
    public var someData: [T]
}
```

And then I create a network request method like this:

```
func request<T: Decodable>(endpoint: Endpoint, responseType: T.Type) async throws -> T
```

And then I use it like this:

```
typealias Response = MyDecodable<SomeDataDecodable>

let responseExample = try await webservice.request(endpoint: .SomeEndpoint, responseType: Response.self)
dump(responseExample)
```

Hope it helps!